# How to check if the CSV file contains equal number of delimiters using unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have some files containing 3 types of delimiters (comma, semicolon, pipe) in random files. I want to check if the file contains the same number of delimiters or field separators in all lines of the files. If there is mismatch in the count of delimiters in the rows, I would like to move the file to the rejected folder. Could you please help me with the script. I am very new to the shell scripting

Comment: Please ask a concrete question about some programming problem. Your posting is too broad, and it doesn't even contain a question.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the confusion. Question is simple, I would like to see if the count of  delimiters in all the lines of the file is same.. If the count is mismatch the files should move to the rejected folder.

Comment: This is the program you want to implement, but we still don't know where you got stuck. For instance, is it that you would like to know how to move a file? Or how to count the number of different delimiters in a line? You don't expect anyone to write the complete program for you, do you?

Comment: Hi, Its that I want to count the number of delimiters in the file, if the count is not matching in the rows the file needs to be moved to the rejected folder.

Comment: Look into csvkit

Comment: @KiranChapidi : This is a bit unclear. You should at least provide a concrete example, but: Why do you want to implement the whole thing in Posix Shell? In particular, if you need a count for each delimiter separately, this would be easier in a more general programming language.

Comment: @Shawn : csvkit is mostly for CSV files, so this doesn't seem to apply here (because he seemingly has a mix of different delimiters in each line). Admittedly, the OP is very unclear in his question, so unless we see a concrete example, we can't recommend much.

Comment: Hi @user1934428 , lets say for example a file called HrExit contains 100 rows with semicolon as delimiter. In all rows there is a count of 10 semicolons but in 2nd and 3rd row there are only 8 semicolons. So this file needs to be moved to the rejected folder.Since this file HrExit is considered as an invalid file.

Comment: @user193428 in particular OP needs to look into [csvclean](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/scripts/csvclean.html).

Comment: @KiranChapidi : You should update your posting with this explanation. One possibility to do it is to loop over each line of a file and count the semicolons in each line. As soon as the count in one line differs from the one of the previous line, you know that you can reject the file.

Comment: Hi @user193428, exactly I am looking for this. Thank you so much.